Firestore Not Charging Document Reads for No-Result Queries: Undocumented Behavior?
I've been testing Firestore queries from Unity and noticed a discrepancy between documented and observed behavior regarding charges for queries that return no results.
According to Firestore documentation:

There is a minimum charge of one document read for each query that you perform, even if the query returns no results.

I noticed that wasn't always the case and to confirm it, I did some tests:

Ran 6 no-result queries and 1 query returning one single document. These were queries that I run very often.
I waited 30 minutes: only 1 read was reflected in either Firestore or Google Cloud usage panel.
I did a subsequent test with a new, never-before-run no-result query, to check if Firestore is doing some caching server-side, and only charges a read the first time a query with no results is run. But after waiting another 30min, the usage panels also showed 0 reads.

According to these tests, my conclusions are:

Queries returning no results are not reflected in the Usage panel (they are not charged with one document read), at least not within the next 30 minutes.
Only queries that return documents are being counted as reads.
This behavior persists even for first-time queries that couldn't have been cached server-side.

Is this undocumented behavior or am I missing something? Has anyone else observed similar results? Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated.
Note: I'm querying from the Unity Editor (Windows PC). The Unity SDK doesn't allow setting Source Options. My understanding is that this uses Firestore's default behavior: attempting to fetch the latest document snapshot from the database, only using offline cache if the network is unavailable or the request times out.

Here is the answer to my own question https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/monitor-usage#usage_dashboard_and_billing_reports

The Firestore usage dashboards in the Firebase and Cloud consoles
provide an estimate of usage. They can help you identify spikes in
usage. However, the dashboard is not an exact view of billed
operations. Billed usage is likely higher. In all cases of
discrepancy, the billing report takes precedence over the usage
dashboard.
Operations that cause discrepancies between the usage dashboard and
billed usage include:

Queries that return zero results. Queries
with zero results incur a cost of one read operation. This usage is
billed but does not appear in the usage dashboard.


